# how to use Oauth2 in zend FW2

Tags: php, oauth, zend-framework2

and thanx for reading, I'm trying to use Oauth with zend 2 by following [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zendoauth.introduction.html) tutorial
but it seems Expired and all goes wrong with me, the last code I tried in my controller is:

```
$config = array(
             // all these urls from details tab for my application
            'siteUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/token',
            'requesttokenUrl'=> 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            'accesstokenUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            'authorizeUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
            'consumerKey' => 'API key from twitter api Keys tab',
            'consumerSecret' => 'THE API secret from twitter api Keys tab'
        );
        // fetch a request token
            $token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
        // persist the token to storage
            $_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($token);

        // redirect the user
            $consumer->redirect(array('oauth_token' => urlencode(serialize($token))));
```

and this leads me to this page:
[image]

I don't know If this code is right and why I get this result.
is there any tutorial to lead me to do it right, or can any one help me with this?
any idea is appreciated, Thanx in advance.

Comment: are you attempting to use OAuth for 'login with twitter' functionality? I'm guessing you've already setup the OAuth 2 server on your ZF2 site?

Comment: No friend I've already lost my job ...